# Validation trouble with CakePHP

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, preg-match, cakephp-2.4

I've got a problem with CakePHP's validation system : to save my data, I use the "array-formatted data" method like this :

```
$this->ReleveCompteur->save($tempData, false, $fieldList)
```

If I set the validation parameter to "true", it always returns me `This field cannot be left blank`

Here is my validation rules in my model :

```
public $validate = array(
    'PERKEY' => 'alphaNumeric',
    'RCO_TITLE' => 'alphaNumeric',
    'RCO_SUPPLIER_SERIAL_NUMBER'  => 'alphaNumeric',
    'PER_EMAIL' => 'email',
    'ASA_COUNTER_ID' => 'numeric',
    'CST_STATEMENT_DATE' => 'date',
    'CST_STATEMENT_QUANTITY' => 'numeric'
);
```

If I set the validation parameter to "false", everything is alright and I've got the right data in my database.
I don't understand why my validation does not work. All the data are correctly passed.

Here is what the validation returns me :

```
["The Post could not be saved. Please, try again.", 
    {"RCO_TITLE":["This field cannot be left blank", "This field cannot be left blank"], 
            "CST_STATEMENT_DATE":["This field cannot be left blank", "This field cannot be left blank"]}, 
    {"CST_STATEMENT_QUANTITY":["3231", "321312", "231"], "PER_KEY1":["745632", "745632", "745658"], 
            "RCO_TITLE":["1.018.462", "1.018.462", "1.018.462"], 
            "RCO_SUPPLIER_SERIAL_NUMBER":["0208800817", "6508410817", "3608850817"], 
            "PER_EMAIL":["johndoe@domain.com", "johndoe@domain.com", "johndoe@domain.com"],
            "ASA_COUNTER_ID":["105", "108", "109"], 
            "cpt":"3", 
            "CODE_ACCES":"474125gh69474125gh69"}, 
    {"RCO_TITLE":["This field cannot be left blank", "This field cannot be left blank"], 
            "CST_STATEMENT_DATE":["This field cannot be left blank", "This field cannot be left blank"]}]
```

Here is what is in the "POST"

```
ASA_COUNTER_ID[]    105
ASA_COUNTER_ID[]    108
ASA_COUNTER_ID[]    109
CODE_ACCES  474125gh69474125gh69
CST_STATEMENT_QUANTITY[]    3231
CST_STATEMENT_QUANTITY[]    321312
CST_STATEMENT_QUANTITY[]    231
PER_EMAIL[] johndoe@domain.com
PER_EMAIL[] johndoe@domain.com
PER_EMAIL[] johndoe@domain.com
PER_KEY1[]  745632
PER_KEY1[]  745632
PER_KEY1[]  745658
RCO_SUPPLIER_SERIAL_NUMBE...    0208800817
RCO_SUPPLIER_SERIAL_NUMBE...    6508410817
RCO_SUPPLIER_SERIAL_NUMBE...    3608850817
RCO_TITLE[] 1.018.462
RCO_TITLE[] 1.018.462
RCO_TITLE[] 1.018.462
_method POST
cpt 3
```

My problem is that I have to insert many rows at once in one table. I get the number of row that I have to insert from another table. Then, I use a loop to create the form and for each field, I insert the data in the database.

Can someone give me a hand or just explain to me what I am doing wrong? It would be much appreciated! Thank you very much!

Here's my Controller :

```
<?php

class ReleveCompteursController extends AppController {

public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Js' => array('Jquery'),'Ajax','Javascript');

public $components = array('RequestHandler');

public function index() {

    $cpt = ClassRegistry::init('ListeCompteur')->find('all', array('conditions' => array('ListeCompteur.CODE_ACCES' => '474125gh69474125gh69'), 'order'=>array('ListeCompteur.PER_KEY1 ASC')));
    $this->set('cpt', $cpt);

}

public function add() {

    if (!empty($this->data)) {

        for ($i = 0; $i < $this->data['cpt']; $i++) {

            $tempData = array(
                'PER_KEY1' => $this->data['PER_KEY1'][$i],
                'RCO_TITLE' => $this->data['RCO_TITLE'][$i],
                'RCO_SUPPLIER_SERIAL_NUMBER' => $this->data['RCO_SUPPLIER_SERIAL_NUMBER'][$i],
                'PER_EMAIL' => $this->data['PER_EMAIL'][$i],
                'ASA_COUNTER_ID' => $this->data['ASA_COUNTER_ID'][$i],
                'CST_STATEMENT_DATE' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'CST_STATEMENT_QUANTITY' => $this->data['CST_STATEMENT_QUANTITY'][$i]
               );

            $fieldList = array('PER_KEY1','RCO_TITLE','RCO_SUPPLIER_SERIAL_NUMBER','PER_EMAIL','ASA_COUNTER_ID','CST_STATEMENT_DATE','CST_STATEMENT_QUANTITY');

            $previous = $this->ReleveCompteur->find('first', array('conditions' => array('ReleveCompteur.ASA_COUNTER_ID' => $this->data['ASA_COUNTER_ID'][$i])));
            if( !empty( $previous ) ) {
                $tempData['ASA_COUNTER_ID'] = $previous[ 'ReleveCompteur' ][ 'ASA_COUNTER_ID' ];                  
            }
            else {
                $this->ReleveCompteur->create();
            }

            if ($this->ReleveCompteur->save($tempData, false, $fieldList)) {
               $message = __('The Post has been saved.', true);
               $Post = 'OK';
               $data = $this->data;
               $errors = '';
            }
            else {
                $message = __('The Post could not be saved. Please, try again.', true);
                $Post = $this->ReleveCompteur->invalidFields();
                $data = $this->data;
                $errors = $this->ReleveCompteur->validationErrors;
            }
        }

        //Via AJAX
        if($this->request->isAjax()){

            $array = array($message, $Post, $data, $errors);
            return new CakeResponse(array('body' => json_encode($array)));
        }
        else{

            $this->Session->setFlash($message);
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }

    }       
}
}
```

Here is my View :

```
<!-- File: /app/View/ReleveCompteurs/index.ctp -->

<?php

    echo $this->Form->create('ReleveCompteur', array('default' => false, 'id' =>'ReleveCompteurForm', 'type' => 'post', 'action' => '#'));
    $i = 1;
    $perKey1 = '';
    $cptSize = sizeof($cpt);

    foreach($cpt as $item) : 

        if ($perKey1 != $item['ListeCompteur']['PER_KEY1']) { 

            $perKey1 = $item['ListeCompteur']['PER_KEY1'];

            ?>

            <dl>

                <dt>Client : <?php echo $item['ListeCompteur']['PER_KEY1']; ?></dt>

        <?php } ?>

        <dd><?php echo $item['ListeCompteur']['RCO_TITLE']; ?></dd>

        <?php 

        echo $this->Form->input('CST_STATEMENT_QUANTITY', 
                                    array(
                                    'label' => array(
                                        'text' => 'Etat du compteur'
                                        ),
                                    'name' => "CST_STATEMENT_QUANTITY[]",
                                    'id' => "CST_STATEMENT_QUANTITY[]",
                                    'placeholder' => 'Etat du compteur',
                                    'error' => array(
                                        'attributes' => array(
                                            'wrap' => 'div', 
                                            'class' => 'alert-box'
                                            )
                                        )
                                    )
                                );

        echo $this->Form->input('PER_KEY1', 
                                array('type' => 'hidden', 
                                    'value' => $item['ListeCompteur']['PER_KEY1'],
                                    'name' => "PER_KEY1[]",
                                    'id' => "PER_KEY1[]")
                                );

        echo $this->Form->input('RCO_TITLE', 
                                array('type' => 'hidden', 
                                    'value' => $item['ListeCompteur']['RCO_TITLE'],
                                    'name' => "RCO_TITLE[]",
                                    'id' => "RCO_TITLE[]")
                                );

        echo $this->Form->input('RCO_SUPPLIER_SERIAL_NUMBER', 
                                array('type' => 'hidden', 
                                    'value' => $item['ListeCompteur']['RCO_SUPPLIER_SERIAL_NUMBER'],
                                    'name' => "RCO_SUPPLIER_SERIAL_NUMBER[]",
                                    'id' => "RCO_SUPPLIER_SERIAL_NUMBER[]")
                                );

        echo $this->Form->input('PER_EMAIL', 
                                array('type' => 'hidden', 
                                    'value' => $item['ListeCompteur']['PER_EMAIL'],
                                    'name' => "PER_EMAIL[]",
                                    'id' => "PER_EMAIL[]")
                                );

        echo $this->Form->input('ASA_COUNTER_ID', 
                                array('type' => 'hidden', 
                                    'value' => $item['ListeCompteur']['ASA_COUNTER_ID'],
                                    'name' => "ASA_COUNTER_ID[]",
                                    'id' => "ASA_COUNTER_ID[]")
                                );

        if ($perKey1 != $item['ListeCompteur']['PER_KEY1'] || $i == $cptSize) { ?>

            </dl>

        <?php }

        $i++;

    endforeach; 

    echo $this->Form->input('cpt', 
                            array('type' => 'hidden', 
                                'value' => $cptSize,
                                'name' => "cpt",
                                'id' => "cpt")
                            );

    echo $this->Form->input('CODE_ACCES', 
                            array('type' => 'hidden', 
                                'value' => $cpt[0]['ListeCompteur']['CODE_ACCES'],
                                'name' => "CODE_ACCES",
                                'id' => "CODE_ACCES")
                            );

    echo $this->Form->end('Sauvegarder');

?>



<?php 

    //URL du Controller
    $url = Router::url(array('controller' => 'ReleveCompteurs','action' => 'add'));
?>
<script>

  $('#ReleveCompteurForm').submit(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php  echo $url; ?>",
        data: form,
        success: function(data){
            $.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: What field cannot be left blank?

Comment: Sorry! I edited my post! ;)

Comment: Why are you using save() when this is obviously post data for saveAll() or saveMany() etc?

Comment: it seems that you are not using formHelper to create your form, so the data is not in the way cake expect to be. Please post a print_r of your `$tempData` varialble so we can check. Also post your view code

Comment: I posted my complete code. It is the first time is use CakePHP. May be there is something that I didn't understand. My problem is that I have to insert many rows at once in one table. I get the number of row that I have to insert from another table. Then, I use a loop to create the form and for each field, I insert the data in the database.